# Как правильно присвоить значенее переменой в xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

У меня есть xml документ в котором вот так лежат данные о машинах

```
<машина ......>
<машина ......>
<машина ......>
<машина ......>
```

Мне нужно создать html таблицу в которой будут лежать данные об этих машинах в том числе и их количество. Как мне создать переменную  и присвоить ей количество машин?

я пытался так:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/машина">

<xsl:variable name="a" select="$a+1"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

и разными вариациями подобных конструкций но всегда ничего не выходило

Comment: А переменная вам зачем?

Comment: Вывести в начале таблицы количество машин

Comment: Если нужно пронумеровать элементы, то используйте `xsl:number`. А вообще, приведите пример, что должно получиться в итоге.

Comment: _Переменные_ в xslt на самом деле являются неизменяемыми. Если нужно организовать цикл с изменениями, обычно рекурсивно вызывают шаблон с параметром.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы подсчитать количество элементов, вам нужно использовать функцию `count()`

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/машина)"/>
```